# AWS CodePipeline Doesn't upload artifacts to AWS S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

As an effort to automate the (Android) build and test process, I configured an *AWS code pipeline* that will 1st get the code from *GitHub* and trigger a build (via *aws codebuild*) Build is shown as completed successfully but the artifacts (apk file) generated as a result of the build process isn't uploaded to the s3 bucket (public bucket). The logs clearly say the upload is successful as seen in the screenshots attached[image: ![here]] [image: here]
The *codepipeline* as well shows everything is successful as attached [image: here]

However, if I run **aws codebuild project directly from the aws codebuild screen**, it **does upload** the artifact successfully to the s3 bucket!

I tried changing the bucket permissions to public/non public, etc. So far no success

Answer (score 12, accepted):

CodePipeline will override the CodeBuild's artifact bucket, I guess it's moving the artifacts to its own Bucket. you can see the CodePipeline's bucket by running the below command.

```
codepipeline get-pipeline --name PipelineName--query pipeline.[artifactStore]

[
    {
        "type": "S3",
        "location": "codepipeline-us-east-1-xxxxxxxx"
    }
]
```

If you are using CloudFormation to create the pipeline you configure the bucket using [ArtifactStore](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-codepipeline-pipeline.html#cfn-codepipeline-pipeline-artifactstore).

**Update ArtifactStore in CodePipeline:**
Currently, I don't see a way to update the ArtifactStore through Console but it can be done with `update-pipeline` command.

Get the pipleline details:

```
aws codepipeline get-pipeline --name MyFirstPipeline >pipeline.json
```

Edit the pipeline to update the S3 Bucket in `artifactStore` and then run the command.

```
aws codepipeline update-pipeline --cli-input-json file://pipeline.json
```

Comment: You seem to be right. The `codepipeline` seems to put it in some other bucket. Is there any option to configure it so that we can decide the s3 bucket?

Comment: you can update your pipeline using CLI or cloudformation, I don't see a way to do it with console right now. Updated the command in the answer.

Comment: +1Upvote. Helped me to debug my problem . Need some extra information https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53370873/codepipeline-restricting-artifact-properties-in-codebuild

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem, couldn't see the `MyAppBuild` folder in S3 that was meant to hold CodeBuild artifacts. Logged out of the web console and back in again and the folder was now visible.