# AWS CodePiplene not upload file to the S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I have AWS CodePipline with these steps:

[image]

When I run CodeBuild phase manually 2 artifacts successfully uploaded to the s3.

[image]

When I change code and push it to CodeCommit pipeline executes successfully, but artifacts don't upload to the S3 bucket. When I read the pipeline logs it asserts that 2 files uploaded successfully to the S3 bucket. but files are not in the S3 bucket.

Both Pipeline and CodeBuild use the same S3 bucket. these are Pipeline logs. The last 3 lines of log assert that 2 artifacts successfully uploaded to the S# bucket.

```
Container] 2020/08/24 08:25:55 Phase complete: POST_BUILD State: SUCCEEDED
[Container] 2020/08/24 08:25:55 Phase context status code:  Message: 
[Container] 2020/08/24 08:25:55 Expanding base directory path: ./build-artifacts
[Container] 2020/08/24 08:25:55 Assembling file list
[Container] 2020/08/24 08:25:55 Expanding ./build-artifacts
[Container] 2020/08/24 08:25:55 Expanding file paths for base directory ./build-artifacts
[Container] 2020/08/24 08:25:55 Assembling file list
[Container] 2020/08/24 08:25:55 Expanding **/*
[Container] 2020/08/24 08:25:55 Found 2 file(s)
[Container] 2020/08/24 08:25:56 Phase complete: UPLOAD_ARTIFACTS State: SUCCEEDED
[Container] 2020/08/24 08:25:56 Phase context status code:  Message:
```

Comment: I read this post before, but it does not help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49291962/aws-codepipeline-doesnt-upload-artifacts-to-aws-s3

Comment: Have you checked CodePipeline bucket? CodeBuild should use it to deploy artifacts. It will be zipped and have some random name without an extention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained in the comments, the reason why you can't see the artifacts in your bucket is that CodePipeline (CP) will store it in **CP's bucket**. You can inspect the CP's bucket.

The **artifacts will be zipped**, although the file in the bucket will have no extension and will have a random name. You can download the file, add `zip` extension and unpack to verify.

One way to deploy to S3 is through a `Deploy` action and [Amazaon S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/reference-pipeline-structure.html) action provider. But this will just deploy the zip, it will not unpack it. I don't think this is what you are aiming for.

The alternative is to use **AWS CLI** in your CodeBuild project to simply copy "manually" the artifacts to the desired bucket. This probably would be the **easiest way**.

Answer (score 0):

CodePipeline will override the CodeBuild's artifact bucket, I guess it's moving the artifacts to its own Bucket. you can see the CodePipeline's bucket by running the below command.

```
codepipeline get-pipeline --name PipelineName--query pipeline.[artifactStore]

[
    {
        "type": "S3",
        "location": "codepipeline-us-east-1-xxxxxxxx"
    }
]
```

If you are using CloudFormation to create the pipeline you configure the bucket using [ArtifactStore](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-codepipeline-pipeline.html#cfn-codepipeline-pipeline-artifactstore).

**Update ArtifactStore in CodePipeline:**
Currently, I don't see a way to update the ArtifactStore through Console but it can be done with `update-pipeline` command.

Get the pipleline details:

```
aws codepipeline get-pipeline --name MyFirstPipeline >pipeline.json
```

Edit the pipeline to update the S3 Bucket in `artifactStore` and then run the command.

```
aws codepipeline update-pipeline --cli-input-json file://pipeline.json
```

Answer Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49292819/11758843

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are not able to see the artifacts is because codepipeline is storing the artifacts in it's own pipeline.

Whenever a codepipeline is created in a region,AWS codepipeline creates a s3 bucket in that region which it uses to store the artifacts for all the pipelines which are created in that region.

If you want to upload the artifacts in a separate s3 bucket you can use
aws s3 cli for that

**Example**

- `AWS s3 sync codebuild/*/<filename> s3://<s3 bucket name>`